# Android WebView - Runtime Permissions in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, webview, permissions

I have an Android app that makes heavy use of Android's WebView. With the new runtime permissions that have been added with 6.0, this presents a challenge for me when trying to handle certain permission requests.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has the `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions set, because there's a page in my WebView that uses Google Maps and gets the users location for directions purposes. I assumed that the WebView would gracefully handle this permission request for 6.0 users, since I'm not making any calls in the Android code to get the user's location. iOS devices handle their runtime permissions this same way. All of the calls to get the location are done via the Google Maps API in that page's JavaScript.

For something like importing a contact, which DOES require Android code on my end, I'm able to request the permission as they described in their [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). I had no issues here, because I'm working directly with the `WRITE_CONTACTS` and `READ_CONTACTS` permissions in my code. That isn't the case for the situation I described above.

How should runtime permissions be handled for WebViews that make use of permissions that Android classifies as "dangerous"?

Comment: I fail to see what the material difference is. In both cases, you have the permissions in your manifest. In both cases, the permissions are `dangerous`. In both cases, you are using APIs (`WebView` and `ContentResolver`) that need for you to have requested and received permission from the user before they can perform `dangerous` operations. Why would `WebView` be any different than `ContentResolver` in this case?

Comment: Are you saying I should request all of the permissions used by the WebView when it's first instantiated? Otherwise I don't currently have a way to capture the request at the time of use (which I believe was the intention of adding runtime permissions). I could use the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to know when the maps page loads and request the permission then. But I didn't think adding these permissions would require that much of a change. I'm comparing this experience to how it's done in iOS, which is what I thought they were trying to achieve.

Comment: "Are you saying I should request all of the permissions used by the WebView when it's first instantiated?" -- I'd phrase it as "before you might load a Web page that attempts to use location APIs". "I believe was the intention of adding runtime permissions" -- IMHO, the intention was to not have to ask for permissions that the app might not need until a point closer to when the app needs them. Depending on flow, though, that might require asking for them on the first run after install (e.g., a Web browser, that doesn't know when it might get a Web page that makes location requests).

Comment: That was my interpretation of how permissions should be used too - request the permission closer to when the it's about to be used instead of when the app is first installed. I really appreciate the response. Thanks for the assistance.